# jQuery order of execution - appended information before animation

Tags: jquery

I have a curious problem in jQuery regarding order of execution. The code below works pretty much as designed, but the closeButton div that is appended at the end, after all the animations and overflow protection removal, appears before the animations.

What causes this behaviour, and what's the best way to deal with it?

```
        $('.infoRight .hoverIcon').click(
            function(){
                $(this).hide();//hide hover icon. Needed as it would otherwise remain visible until mouse-off
                $(this).parent()
                    .clone(false)//create a copy of the item
                    .addClass('expandinator')//give appropriate classes to ensure appropriate styling
                    .addClass('expandinatorright')
                    .appendTo($(this).parent());//place clone in its parent.
                $('.expandinatorright').animate({//change to colour for expanded info
                    backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
                    color: "#124191"
                }, 300 , function() {
                    $('.expandinatorright').animate({//biggify
                        width: "510px"
                    }, 150, function() {
                        $('.expandinatorright').css('overflow', 'visible', function() {});//remove overflow protection
                        $('<div class="closeButton"></div>').appendTo('.expandinatorright');//add a close button
                    });
                });
            }
        );
```

Comment: You have to post an example of your work in jsfiddle.net. I did not get much out of that, but, you are using the animate-callback-function. This gets fired after the animation is finished. Is this by design?

Comment: Absolutely - what I want is for that div of class closeButton to only be placed once all animations and stuff are finished, but the problem is that it doesn't appear to be executed in the callback, but rather BEFORE the animations even happen. I'll see if I can get it on jsfiddle, but it would be rather a lot of work to strip out everything irrelevant/publically viewable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do here is add `display:none` property to the class "closeButton". Once you are done with the animation stuff do something like $(".closeButton").show();
Infact you can even chain the show() function with what you are doing currently, something like :-

```
$('.infoRight .hoverIcon').click(
            function(){
                $(this).hide();//hide hover icon. Needed as it would otherwise remain visible until mouse-off
                $(this).parent()
                    .clone(false)//create a copy of the item
                    .addClass('expandinator')//give appropriate classes to ensure appropriate styling
                    .addClass('expandinatorright')
                    .appendTo($(this).parent());//place clone in its parent.
                $('.expandinatorright').animate({//change to colour for expanded info
                    backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
                    color: "#124191"
                }, 300 , function() {
                    $('.expandinatorright').animate({//biggify
                        width: "510px"
                    }, 150, function() {
                        $('.expandinatorright').css('overflow', 'visible', function() {});//remove overflow protection
                        $('<div class="closeButton"></div>').appendTo('.expandinatorright').show();//add a close button
                    });
                });
            }
        );
```

Comment: It works! Why is it that the div appears to be appended before the code to do so should be executed?  Thanks, by the way :)

Comment: I'm not too sure why this should happen, u could also try something like this inside the $('.expandinatorright').animate callback function :-  `$('.expandinatorright').css('overflow', 'visible', function() {}).append('<div class="closeButton"></div>')`   i guess if u try this u need not put that display:none property